# Height of algebraic numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I would like to find effective upper bound for the height of $a+b$ and $a/b$ and $ab$ knowing the heights of $a$ and $b$. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, what is the height?

Answer (score 19):

If you know only heights of $a$ and $b$, you may estimate heights of $a+b$, $a/b$ and $ab$. Assuming that $h$ is an absolute (Weil) height:
$$h(ab)\leq h(a)+h(b)$$
$$h(a/b)\leq h(a)+h(b)$$
$$h(a+b)\leq\log 2 +h(a)+h(b)$$
This bounds are sharp. You may find this, for example, in M. Waldschmidt "Diophantine approximation on linear algebraic groups", Chapter 3.

Comment: $h(a)$ is also called the absolute logarithmic height of $a$, defined by $1/[K:Q] \log H_K(a)$, where $H_K(a)$ is the product of all of the embeddings (with multiplicity) of $a$ that land outside the complex unit circle. In other words, $h(a) = 1/d M(a)$, where $M(a)$ is the Mahler measure of $a$.

Comment: @KevinO'Bryant That's only correct if $\alpha$ is an algebraic integer. For algebraic numbers, one either needs to also use $p$-adic embeddings, or take the norm of the "denominator ideal" of $\alpha$. To see why, consider $\alpha=\frac12$. There are no complex embeddings for which $\alpha$ lies outside the unit circle, but $H_{\mathbb Q}(\alpha)=2$, not $1$.

Answer (score 12):

There are standard estimates for the heights of algebraic numbers $a_1,...,a_n$ in terms of their elementary symmetric functions $s_1,...,s_n$, or equivalently, estimates relating the heights of the roots of a polynomial to the heights of its coefficients. You can find this in many textbooks, including for example my *Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves* (Theorem VIII.5.9) or Lang's *Fundamentals of Diophantine Geometry* (Chapter 3, Section 2). The estimate is 
$$
  \sum_{i=1}^n h(a_i) - n\log(2) \le h([1,s_1,...,s_n]) 
  \le \sum_{i=1}^n h(a_i) + (n-1)\log(2).
$$

Comment: Do these references contain information about height of intersection\union\projection of varieties in terms of the height of the varieties?

Comment: @BennyZak No, they don't discuss the heights of varieties. You might find information of that sort in one of the following articles: An Arithmetic Analogue of Bezout's Theorem, David McKinnon, Compositio Mathematica, April 2001, Volume 126, Issue 2, pp 147–155; or Heights of projective varieties and positive Green forms, J.-B. Bost, H. Gillet and C. Soulé,  J. Amer. Math. Soc. 7 (1994), 903-1027.

Answer (score 5):

If $a$ is the root of a characteristic polynomial of $M$ and $b$ is the root of the characteristic polynomial of $N,$ then $ab$ is a root of the charcteristic polynomial of $M \otimes N,$ and $a+b$ is a root of the characteristic polynomial of $M \otimes I + I \otimes N.$ That should be enough to compute the height.

Comment: Thanks, Igor. Can you give the definition of the tensor product of two polynomials. 

Comment: M and N are matrices, and the tensor product is the thing they call the block product.

Comment: The tensor product is of MATRICES $M$ and $N,$ of which $a$ and $b$ are eigenvalues (you can take $M$ and $N$ to be the companion matrices of the minimal polynomials of $a, b$).



Comment: Sorry to duplicate, Igor!

Comment: No problem, I was going to apologize to you for same...

Answer (score 2):

I too was looking for the answer to the same question. It seems necessary to define "height" since there are of course several variants in use. The height $h(a)$ I am interested in is the maximum of the absolute values of the coefficients of the minimal polynomial of the algebraic number $a$. Note that the first answer refers to a different notion of height, since, for example,

$9 = h(9) = h(3 \cdot 3) \not \leq h(3) + h(3) = 3 + 3 = 6.$

I imagine there must be upper bounds of the form

$h(ab) \leq f(d) h(a)^{g(d)} h(b)^{g(d)}$

for some simple functions $f$ and $g$, where $d$ is the degree of a field extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ containing both $a$ and $b$, for example.

Are there any such results in the literature, and similarly for $h(a+b)$ and $h(a/b)$?

Comment: I think Oleg's height is the log of your height.

Comment: Thanks Will. I believe Oleg's height is the logarithmic Weil height, defined in terms of the Mahler measure. It is no doubt related to my "naive" height in some way, but I don't think it's simply the log of it. Or at least, it's far from obvious to me... 

Comment: This height is the "usual height", and is often written with a capital $H$ to distinguish it from the absolute logarithmic height. Waldschmidt (Lemma 3.11) reports $\frac1d H(a) - \log 2 \leq h(a) \leq \frac1d H(a) + \frac{1}{2d} \log(d+1)$, which can be combined with the bounds on other answers to bound $H(a+b)$ and $H(a/b)$.

Comment: Thanks very much Kevin for the pointer. I just took Waldschmidt's book out and indeed it contains all the results I need! (By the way, your statement of Lemma 3.11 is missing an application of $\log(-)$ to $H(a)$ on both instances.)